# Why can't this PowerShell script find Local Users or Groups?

Tags: windows, security, powershell, scripting

I pulled [this](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-domain-user-or-group-to-local-administrators-with-powershell/) script from online which claims to be able to turn entire user groups into Local Administrators, which seems it would suit my goal perfectly (Turning all Standard Users into Local Admins). However, it gives the following error.

> Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "A member could not be added to or removed from the local group because the member does not exist."

I followed the example given on the site, and tried both the "Users" group for a paramater, as well as individually targeting a Standard User profile I made by name, called "Test01". In both cases, the same error is always thrown. I have checked under the Groups snap-in in the System Console, and the account and group were definitely both spelled correctly. Here is the script for convenience, as well as the two different ways I tried executing it at the top. I leave the Computer name out, because the script successfully finds it if not specified.

```
PS C:\> Set-LocalAdminGroupMembers.ps1 -ObjectType User -ObjectName "WORKGROUP\Test01"

PS C:\> Set-LocalAdminGroupMembers.ps1 -ObjectType Group -ObjectName "WORKGROUP\Users"

[CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [ValidateSet("User","Group")]
    [String]
    $ObjectType,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
    [ValidateScript({($_.split("\").count -eq 2)})]
    [string]$ObjectName,
    [Parameter(Position=3)]
    [String[]]$ComputerName=$env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

$ResultsFile = "c:\temp\ResultsofLocalGroupAddition.csv"
$ObjDomain = $ObjectName.Split("\")[0]
$ObjName = $ObjectName.Split("\")[1]
$ComputerCount = $ComputerName.Count
$count = 0
Add-Content -Path $ResultsFile -Value "ComputerName,Status,Comments"
foreach($Computer in $ComputerName) {
    $count++
    $Status=$null
    $Comment = $null
    Write-Host ("{0}. Working on {1}" -f $Count, $Computer)
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Write-Verbose "$Computer : Online"
        try {
            $GroupObj = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/Administrators"
            $GroupObj.Add("WinNT://$ObjDomain/$ObjName")
            $Status = "Success"
            $Comment = "Added $ObjectName $ObjectType to Local administrators group"
            Write-Verbose "Successfully added $ObjectName $ObjectType to $Computer"
        } catch {
            $Status = "Failed"
            $Comment = $_.toString().replace("`n","").replace("`r","")
            Write-Verbose "Failed to add $ObjectName $ObjectType to $Computer"
        }

        Add-Content -Path $ResultsFile -Value ("{0},{1},{2}" -f $Computer,$Status,$Comment )    

    } else {
        Write-Warning "$Computer : Offline"
        Add-Content -Path $ResultsFile -Value ("{0},{1}" -f $Computer,"Offline")
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are trying to add a local user account to the local administrators group you need to specify the account correctly. The account would not be `WinNT://$ObjDomain/$ObjName`, it would be `WinNT://$Computer/$ObjName`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks! That fixed half of the problem. However my main concern is being able to use the group implementation of this script. With your fix I can successfully pick one account at a time, but am still getting the same error when I try to add by group instead of username. This is important because I want to be able to redeploy this script across multiple machines. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to extract the users from a local group, and add each of them to the local admin group, or you just want to add the local group to the local admin group?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Really the end goal is to add any users (besides the default "guest" and "admin")  that aren't local administrators to the local admin group. Also the two network admin accounts that currently exist should not be tampered with. I was speaking with a colleague later on last afternoon and he informed me that I may be able to do this with a couple of simple DOS commands... which is what I'm now looking for.